Wirelessly mirroring my desktop to my Sony TV
I would like to stream the desktop of my Ubuntu system to my Sony. Anyone have any advice? The gnome-network-displays can't find the Sony.

Are you sure that the TV supports web casting? Can you cast your phone/windows devices to the TV?

Yes, I used to do with Windows 11.

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu 22.04 How to cast the entire screen with sound
